# Using jdbcTemplate.query with parameters

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have 3 tables in Database Lecture--< LectureGroups >-- Groups.
And I want to get schedule for a certain group on a certain day. I try to do it in this way:

```
@Repository
public class Schedule {

    private static final String GET_GROUP_DAY_SCHEDULE = "SELECT * FROM LECTURES " +
            "INNER JOIN LECTUREGROUPS ON LECTURES.ID = LECTUREGROUPS.LECTUREID " +
            "INNER JOIN GROUPS ON GROUPS.ID = LECTUREGROUPS.GROUPID " +
            "WHERE GROUPID = :GROUPID AND DATE = :DATE";

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Lecture> getGroupDayLectures(int groupId, LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        MapSqlParameterSource parameters =  new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("groupid", groupId)
                .addValue("date", dateTime);
        return jdbcTemplate.query(GET_GROUP_DAY_SCHEDULE, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Lecture.class), parameters);
    }
}
```

But I get an exception in query raw

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

How I can fix it?
I also used variant with

```
private static final String GET_GROUP_DAY_SCHEDULE = "SELECT * FROM LECTURES " +
            "INNER JOIN LECTUREGROUPS ON LECTURES.ID = LECTUREGROUPS.LECTUREID " +
            "INNER JOIN GROUPS ON GROUPS.ID = LECTUREGROUPS.GROUPID " +
            "WHERE GROUPID = ? AND DATE = ?";

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Lecture> getGroupDayLectures(int groupId, LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(GET_GROUP_DAY_SCHEDULE, new Object[]{groupId, dateTime}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Lecture.class));
    }
```

and it works but return only 1 Lecture in list (it must be 3)

Comment: `JdbcTemplate` doesn't support named parameters, so either you have to use the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` **or** use the second option. If there is only one result your query is wrong or your expectation is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

There is a signature with parameters in the jdbcTemplate class:

```
public <T> List<T> query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper, @Nullable Object... args)
```

So it is very easy to use it in this way

```
private static final String GET_GROUP_DAY_SCHEDULE = "SELECT * FROM LECTURES " +
            "INNER JOIN LECTUREGROUPS ON LECTURES.ID = LECTUREGROUPS.LECTUREID " +
            "INNER JOIN GROUPS ON GROUPS.ID = LECTUREGROUPS.GROUPID " +
            "WHERE GROUPID = ? AND DATE = ?";

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Lecture> getGroupDayLectures(int groupId, LocalDate date) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(GET_GROUP_DAY_SCHEDULE, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Lecture.class), groupId, date);
    }
```